# Ajax update of <span> not working, how to debug

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to create a calendar with php which can be scrolled on the server side. Yesterday I received a good advice on how to implement this with Ajax (my attempts failed). While the answer looks very promising and correct, I do not get it to work. Possibly it is something as simple as a wrong path, but my tries around paths did not work out. And unfortunately, I have no idea how to debug this.

Problem is, clicking the button to update the data (scroll the calendar) does not provide any reaction. However, the initial calendar view is rendered.

file structure:

```dart
index.php
booking1.php
presentation (folder)
   booking2.php
   cal.php
   home.php
```

The client side code as shown in Safari (at the end of the upper section you will find the button for calendar scrolling and at the button the respective script)

```html
 <span id="calendar">
            <section class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card_body">
                                <div class="calendar_month">
                                    <span class="calendar_month_title">
                                        <button onclick="prevMonth()">&lt Sep</button>
                                        Oct
                                    </span>
                                    
// ....


    </section>

    <script scr="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var defaultMonth = 10;
    var defaultYear = 2021;

    var currentMonth = defaultMonth;
    var currentYear = defaultYear;

    function updateCal() {
        $('#calendar').load('presentation/cal.php?month=' + currentMonth + '&year=' + currentYear);
    }

    function nextMonth() {
        currentMonth += 1;
        if (currentMonth == 13) {
            currentMonth = 1;
            currentYear += 1;
        }
        updateCal();
    }

    function prevMonth() {
        currentMonth -= 1;
        if (currentMonth == 0) {
            currentMonth = 12;
            currentYear -= 1;
        }
        updateCal();
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

This is the `presentation/cal.php` file

```php
<?php 
$defaultMonth = date("m");
$defaultYear = date("Y");
$month = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : $defaultMonth;
if (strlen($month) === 1 ) {
    $month = '$month' . strval($month);
}

$year = isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : $defaultYear;
$requestedDate = new DateTime(strval($year) . '-' . strval($month) . '-01');


echo '<section class="container">';
  echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class = "col">';
      echo '<div class = "card"><div class="card_body">';
      getCalendar($requestedDate, true, true, false);
    echo '</div></div>';
  echo '</div>';
echo '</section>';
```

The `booking1.php` from the home directory (the `calendar.php` hosts the `getCalendar()` function)

```php
<?php 

define('HOME_DIR',__DIR__);
require_once __DIR__.'/calendar/calendar.php';
include __DIR__.'/presentation/header.php';
include __DIR__.'/presentation/booking.php';
```

And `presentation/booking2.php`

```php
<section class="container" id="tbd">

<?php
echo '<span id="calendar">';
include __DIR__.'/cal.php';
echo '</span>';

?>
</section>

<script scr="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var defaultMonth = <?php echo date("n") ?>;
  var defaultYear = <?php echo date("Y") ?>;
  
  var currentMonth = defaultMonth;
  var currentYear = defaultYear;
  
  function updateCal() {
    $('#calendar').load('presentation/cal.php?month=' + currentMonth + '&year=' + currentYear);
  }
  
  function nextMonth() {
    currentMonth += 1;
    if(currentMonth == 13) {
      currentMonth = 1;
      currentYear += 1;
    }
    updateCal();
  }
  
  function prevMonth() {
    currentMonth -= 1;
    if(currentMonth == 0) {
      currentMonth = 12;
      currentYear -= 1;
    }
    updateCal();
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Any idea, why the button click provides no reaction? And how would I debug this? This is actually only a small, private side project, and I haven't managed to get Eclipse working with MySQL in such way that I can use Eclipse for debugging. This is why I print variables etc for debugging reasons. But if the page has been successfully rendered and only updating a section fails, this method no longer works (on my level of (non-)expertise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your browser for debugging. In Chrome/Firefox (haven't used Safari), right click and Inspect. Then the `Console` tab will show any javascript error, and you can also do `console.log()` from your code to debug any variables, and the `Network` tab will show you the requests, so you can see if the ajax request is being executed, if it throws error, or what is the data sent and the data recieved.

I would also suggest rewriting code from scratch if possible and improve architecture.

Also:

- From `presentation/booking2.php`, you are doing `.load('presentation/cal.php')` but not sure if you need to put the directory here since you're already inside it, because it might try to go to `presentation/presentation/cal.php`, but again, this you'll see with Browser developer tools in Console and Network
- Don't use a `span`, but a `div`, for the container, it's better use of html tags
- Make sure you're only generating the calendar from one place so you don't repeat code and end up with weird things, I mean, if you have a function that will return your calendar code, you should use that function both the first time when rendering the html, and also in the ajax calls, or better yet, always load the calendar by ajax
- I would recommend writing from scratch a simple page that behaves as you wish, where you properly achieve the effect of loading a block from ajax, and "navigating" it using buttons, then when that works, you can migrate the rest of the code into it and test it step by step in case something breaks so you know when/what caused it and be able to go back and rectify

### Example of loading the calendar initially by ajax

Check https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Note: You're using a quite old version of jQuery but anyways the example should work.

At the end of your `<script>` tag, add:

```
<script>
//...
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "loading initial calendar" );
    updateCal();
});
//...
</script>
```

Comment: Cheers, the Safari console shows status 500, the path looks correct. So this is already a step forward. I was wondering how I could perform the initial load with Ajax, but didn't know how. Is there a 'simple' onLoad script for this?

Comment: Please check the answer again, I have added a way to load the initial calendar. Basically with jQuery you check when the page is "ready", and you execute the function that loads the calendar.

Comment: As for the status 500, well now you know your ajax page has some errors in the PHP and you should be able to debug them from the Network tab. When you click on the ajax request, you can see both the data you send, and the response/error. Anyways you'll just have to debug php errors and see what went wrong.

Comment: My issues appear to be caused by path / require statements. For some strange reason, the code that used to work initially now doesn't when the cal.php file is addressed via Ajax. How do you manage file includes? Unless I am overseeing something, including all files with functions/data models in the initial php (`cal.php`) does not provide the references to functions across the included files (including `model.php` and `myFunctions.php` does not provide `class MyModel` to `myFunction() {...}`

Comment: Well I don't know if I can help with that without specific error messages and full list of code files. AJAX should not have anything to do with PHP. Just make sure the script and all the required functions and clases are loaded. Is the calendar working in any of the scripts? Maybe you can take that script that works and remove the rest of the code, and convert the code to the script you need for ajax. Then leave it in the same directory and change the .load to point to it.